# Getting mousewheel events in DrawArea with python GTK3

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm trying to get a *mousewheel* event inside a Gtk.DrawArea.
Does someone know howto achieve this? The method 
DrawTest.on_scroll() is never called currently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                   

import gi                                                                                                                                                                                
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')                                                                                                                                                         
from gi.repository import Gtk                                                                                                                                                            

class DrawTest(Gtk.DrawingArea):                                                                                                                                                         
    def __init__(self):                                                                                                                                                                  
        super(DrawTest, self).__init__()                                                                                                                                                 
        self.connect("scroll-event", self.on_scroll)                                                                                                                                     

    def on_scroll(self, btn, event):                                                                                                                                                     
        print("Scroll event")                                                                                                                                                            
        return True                                                                                                                                                                      


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):                                                                                                                                                            
    def __init__(self):                                                                                                                                                                  
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()                                                                                                                                               
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())                                                                                                                               

        evtest = DrawTest()                                                                                                                                                              

        self.add(evtest)                                                                                                                                                                 
        self.show_all()                                                                                                                                                                  

    def run(self):                                                                                                                                                                       
        Gtk.main()                                                                                                                                                                       

def main(args):                                                                                                                                                                          
    mainwdw = MainWindow()                                                                                                                                                               
    mainwdw.run()                                                                                                                                                                        
    return 0                                                                                                                                                                             

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                               
    import sys                                                                                                                                                                           
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set or add events that the Gtk.DrawingArea should handle.

Just add this line of code to your DrawTest class in the init method:

```
self.set_events (Gdk.EventMask.ALL_EVENTS_MASK)
```

It should look like this:

```
class DrawTest(Gtk.DrawingArea): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(DrawTest, self).__init__()
        self.set_events (Gdk.EventMask.ALL_EVENTS_MASK)
        self.connect("scroll-event", self.on_scroll)
    ...
```

The [`set_events`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gdk.Window.set_events) method comes from Gtk.Widget class and it says:

> The event mask for a window determines which events will be reported
>   for that window from all master input devices. For example, an event
>   mask including Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK means the window should
>   report button press events. The event mask is the bitwise OR of values
>   from the Gdk.EventMask enumeration.
>
> See the ‘input handling overview [event-masks]’ for details.

For simplicity I've set the [`ALL_EVENTS_MASK`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/flags.html#Gdk.EventMask.ALL_EVENTS_MASK), more on [Gdk.EventMask](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/flags.html#Gdk.EventMask).

PS: Notice that `Gdk.Window` is not the same as `Gtk.Window` as you will see if you read more on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, verified it. In the meantime I was switching to the fabulous pyqtgraph that handles all the details...